# Parse JSON data with Axios and NodeJS Express (matching a schema for mongoose)

Tags: json, node.js, mongoose, schema, axios

I am trying to parse JSON from an API, and because it has a randomly named property whose value is an object (of which has the data I need), I'm having trouble getting the data from it to match with a schema.
Here is a shortened API response just to show the problem I'm having.

```
{
    "data": {
        "1": {
            "id": 1, 
            "name": "First Name",
            "quotes": {
                "USD": {
                    "price": 100
                }
            }
        }, 
        "1027": {
            "id": 1027, 
            "name": "Second Name",
            "quotes": {
                "USD": {
                    "price": 200
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And a shortened schema:

```
var coin = new Mongoose.Schema({
    id: Number,
    name: String,
    quotes: {
        USD: {
            price: Number
        }
    }
});
```

So the question is, how would I grab "1"'s object and "1027"'s object without explicitly naming them. And is my schema syntax correct for the objects in question?

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure about the mongoose piece, but you can get an object's keys with `Object.keys()` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

Then you'll always know the names of the properties regardless of their randomness on each return.

Comment: This returns the array of objectsif you are asking it, Object.values(yourResponse.data)

Answer (score 0):

You can always use the `for...in` loop to check whether this data is what you have looking for

```js
const response = {
  "data": {
    "1": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "First Name",
      "quotes": {
        "USD": {
          "price": 100
        }
      }
    },
    "1027": {
      "id": 1027,
      "name": "Second Name",
      "quotes": {
        "USD": {
          "price": 200
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

for (let key in response.data) {
  if (key === '1') {
    console.log('Hey, I find it')
  }
  console.log(key)
}
```